# How do I match a whole sentence in Javascript Regular Expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a Regular Expression (in Javascript) that will match a specific sentence structure.  In my case, it's "Course ### day ###", where ### can be any 1 to 3 digit number.  Additionally, it can be "week" instead of "day", so "Course ### week ###" is also valid.

So far, I've come up with:

```
var regTest=/^(Course) \d{1,3} (day)|(week) \d{1,3}$/
```

The problem is that this expression matches "Course 9 day 1", which is what I want, but it would also match "Course 9 day 1 scheduled on 07/01/09".

In other words, the following returns a value of 0:

```
"Course 9 day 1".search(regTest)
```

But this one also returns 0:

```
"Course 9 day 1 scheduled on 07/01/09".search(regTest)
```

I want the first test to return 0, but I want the second one to return -1.  I need the expression to ONLY match up until the ### following day/week.  How do you make it to stop at that point?

Comment: Are you trying to extract something from the string or are you just trying to validate that the string matches the pattern?

Answer (score 4):

You need to move the OR (the pipe) into the parenthesis between the day and week:

```
/^(Course) \d{1,3} (day|week) \d{1,3}$/
```

If the pipe is inside the parens then it matches "day" or "week" in that position.  With the pipe not inside of a parens it matches either the first half of the expression (i.e. "Course ### day") or the last half of the expression (i.e. "week ###").

Also, if you are just trying to validate that the string matches the pattern you can use "test" rather than "search":

```
if(/^(Course) \d{1,3} (day|week) \d{1,3}$/.test(someString)) {
    // it matches!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An additional level of grouping is needed:

```
var regTest=/^(Course) \d{1,3} ((day)|(week)) \d{1,3}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
var regTest=/^(Course) \d{1,3} (day|week) \d{1,3}$/
```

(Notice that `(day)|(week)` has changed to `(day|week)`).  Your old regex was actually two, joined with the |.  You see, | is one of the less (least?) tightly binding regex metacharacters, which means that `ab|cd` will match "ab" and "cd", but not "abd" or "acd".

Answer (score 0):

You have everything right except that you need to put the check for `(day)|(week)` in a parenthesis block, i.e.

```
var regTest=/^(Course) \d{1,3} ((day)|(week)) \d{1,3}$/
```

You can actually reduce the statement to

```
var regTest=/^Course \d{1,3} (day|week) \d{1,3}$/
```

BTW, I do know why you don't need the parenthesis around `Course`.  I'm not sure why you don't need them around `day` and `week`.  If I had access to `sed` right know I would like to see how it treated `((day)|(week))` versus `(day|week)`.